# magento locale for zh_HK (Hong Kong)

Tags: php, magento, translation

I need to Convert English to Traditional Chinese Language (zh_HK) ,But i can't found any Locale for that in magento.
I downloaded through some links but that too in english or in zh_HK.xml file.
I am helpless ,If anyone have some idea please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the step :

try this language http://magentocenter.com/traditional-chinese-language-pack-zh_hk/

1. Download the desired translation thru Magento connect via admin.
2. Once installed Go to: System -> Manage Stores -> Create store view. Enter the data and save.
3. Now go to: Configuration -> Current Configuration Scope (Select your language from the dropdown) and on the right side under “Locale options” choose the desired language.

Comment: But when i am trying to download that pack it redirects from http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/traditional-chinese-language-pack-zh-hk-7959.html

to

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/

cant able to download pack.

Comment: have you tried to download from freegento.com and copy paste files in your magento.

Comment: can u send me the Url?

Comment: Thank you..Actually i am having doubt does taiwan locale will suit for hong kong  also??

Comment: does any locale available for hong kong?zh_HK?